# At what points in a Fragment's lifecycle can a user interact with the UI?

Tags: android

When during a Fragment's life cycle do the OnClickListeners associated with Views that are associated with the Fragment respond to user actions?

I realize that the Fragmentis fully visible between onResume() and onPause(), and the Fragment is partially visible between onStart() and onStop(), but I do not know if the OnClickListeners associated with Views associated with the Fragment would respond to user interaction only between onResume() and onPause() or if they would also respond to user interaction between onStart() and onStop().

**EDIT:** Found the answer here: [OnClickListener fired after onPause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432014/onclicklistener-fired-after-onpause)

View touch events can occur independently from Activity/Fragment lifecycles.

Comment: This must be singularly easy to test. If the test throws up an unexpected behaviour, refine the question and include some test code exhibiting the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @PaulHicks From my testing, I would think the answer is no, the user cannot interact with the UI when the Fragment once onPause() has been called.

However, a report shows an “IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState”, and the stack trace shows that the problem originates from one of my OnClickListeners. If my testing was accurate, this should not be possible since onSaveInstanceState() should not be called until after onPause().

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but maybe this will help:

> onResume() makes the fragment begin interacting with the user (based on its containing activity being resumed).
>
> public void onResume ()
>
> Added in API level 11
>
> Called when the fragment is visible to the user and actively running. This is generally tied to Activity.onResume of the containing Activity's lifecycle.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onResume()