# Why onTouchEvent happens after onPause?

Tags: android, lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

Recently I got a crash report with the following trace

```
50:47.306 Activity#onPause
50:47.687 View#onTouchEvent
50:47.693 ...
50:47.812 Activity#onResume
```

where 50 - minutes, 47 - secs, after '.' milliseconds. It happened on Android 7.0, Samsung SM-A510F

How is that possible!?

Comment: Here is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31438795/8161187

Comment: @Greaper Thanks! Just needed such confirmation before adding some defense from that...